# Microsoft Dynamics 365 Plugin Error : You cannot start a transaction with a different isolation level than is already set on the current transaction

Tags: c#, plugins, visual-studio-2015

I am tying to make a custom entity with the name of `Country2` by writing a plugin in C# for Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM. I am trying in this way;

```
// Create the custom entity.
                    CreateEntityRequest createrequest = new CreateEntityRequest
                    {
                        //Define the entity
                        Entity = new EntityMetadata
                        {
                            SchemaName = "Country2",
                            DisplayName = new Label("Country2", _languageCode),
                            DisplayCollectionName = new Label("Countries2", _languageCode),
                            Description = new Label("An entity to store information about cities.", 1033),
                            OwnershipType = OwnershipTypes.UserOwned,
                            IsActivity = false,
                        },

                        // Define the primary attribute for the entity
                        PrimaryAttribute = new StringAttributeMetadata
                        {
                            SchemaName = "new_countryname",
                            RequiredLevel = new AttributeRequiredLevelManagedProperty(AttributeRequiredLevel.None),
                            MaxLength = 100,
                            FormatName = StringFormatName.Text,
                            DisplayName = new Label("Country Name", _languageCode),
                            Description = new Label("The primary attribute for the Country entity.", _languageCode)
                        }

                    };
                    service.Execute(createrequest);
                    //Entity must be published
                    // Add few attributes to the custom activity entity.
                    CreateAttributeRequest fontFamilyAttributeRequest = new CreateAttributeRequest
                        {
                            EntityName = "Country2",
                            Attribute = new StringAttributeMetadata
                            {
                                SchemaName = prefix + "fontfamily",
                                DisplayName = new Label("Font Family", _languageCode),
                                MaxLength = 100
                            }
                        };
                    CreateAttributeResponse fontFamilyAttributeResponse =
                        (CreateAttributeResponse)service.Execute(
                        fontFamilyAttributeRequest);

                    CreateAttributeRequest fontColorAttributeRequest =
                        new CreateAttributeRequest
                        {
                            EntityName = "Country2",
                            Attribute = new StringAttributeMetadata
                            {
                                SchemaName = prefix + "fontcolor",
                                DisplayName = new Label("Font Color", _languageCode),
                                MaxLength = 50
                            }
                        };
                    CreateAttributeResponse fontColorAttributeResponse =
                        (CreateAttributeResponse)service.Execute(
                        fontColorAttributeRequest);

                    CreateAttributeRequest fontSizeAttributeRequest =
                        new CreateAttributeRequest
                        {
                            EntityName = "Country2",
                            Attribute = new IntegerAttributeMetadata
                            {
                                SchemaName = prefix + "fontSize",
                                DisplayName = new Label("Font Size", _languageCode)
                            }
                        };
                    CreateAttributeResponse fontSizeAttributeResponse =
                        (CreateAttributeResponse)service.Execute(
                        fontSizeAttributeRequest);
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("The Country custom entity has been created.");
```

In the above code, I tried to make the `new entity` first then tried to set the `PrimaryAttribute` and at the end `CreateAttributeRequest`.

**But it prompts an error of;**

> You cannot start a transaction with a different isolation level than is already set on the current transaction.
>   Is there any thing wrong here?

Comment: do a google search on the exact error.. this is the first thing I would have done.. also have you used the debugger..?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can create an entity without a custom prefix. Right now your entity is "Country2", I would change it to "new_country2" Your code follows pretty closely to the example provided online https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509014.aspx

Try switching it to exactly like online to see if the entity/attribute is created with the same name from that article.